# .Net core Web API set json/model values to NULL

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a .Net core Web API that accepts following JSON: (RequestModel)

```
{
    "isSpecimen": true,   
    "forms": {
        "cyber": {           
            "abc1": {
                "formOrder": 1,
                "endNumber": "1",
                "selected": true,
                "aggLimit": 5000000.0,
                "Date": "2016-12-14T00:00:00.00Z"
            },
            "abc2": {
                "formOrder": 2,
                "endNumber": "4",
                "selected": false,
                "aggLimit": 50000.0,
                "Date": "2019-12-14T00:00:00.00Z"
            },
        }
    }
}
```

Following are the model classes:

```
public class RequestModel
{
   public FormsModel Forms { get; set; }
   public bool IsSpecimen { get; set; }
}

public abstract class BaseFormInfo
{
    public bool Selected { get; set; }
    public int? FormOrder { get; set; }
    public virtual string FormKey { get; set; }
}

public class FormsModel
{
    public ExcessFormsModel? Excess { get; set; }
    public CyberFormsModel? Cyber { get; set; }
}

public class CyberFormsModel
{
    public Abc1? abc1 { get; set; }
    public Abc2? abc2 { get; set; }
    public Abc3? abc3 { get; set; }
}

public class Abc1: BaseFormInfo
{
     public override string FormKey => "Abc1";
     public decimal? aggLimit{ get; set; }
     public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
     public string? endNumber{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to update the model to set the field values to NULL for the classes where
"selected": true

For e.g: "abc1" has "selected": true

```
"cyber": {           
        "abc1": {
            "formOrder": null,
            "endNumber": null,
            "selected": true,
            "aggLimit": null,
            "Date": null
        },
}
```

How do I iterate through the JSON data to set the values to NULL?

Comment: Why do think you need to iterate JSON (i.e. string) Data? Mutate the model and serialize again.

Comment: You've got all the tools there, so give it a go... Just null the values inside the controller method after you receive the request but before you process it.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by using custom model binding. First parse the JSON string into JObject, then traverse the JSON structure to find the object under cyber. For each cyber, check whether the "selected" attribute is true. If so, set all attributes except "selected" to empty. After modifying the JSON, reconvert the JObject to a string. In addition, you can hide the FormKey by adding JsonIgnore to the FormKey attribute. Here is an example You can use it as a reference :

```
public abstract class BaseFormInfo
{
     public bool Selected { get; set; }
     public int? FormOrder { get; set; }
     [JsonIgnore]
     public virtual string FormKey { get; set; }
}
```

My Controller:

```
[HttpPost]

public IActionResult Update([ModelBinder(typeof(MyModelBinder))]  RequestModel request)

{
  
    return Ok(request);

}
```

My Modelbinder:

```
public class MyModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
     public async Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
     {
         if (bindingContext == null)
         {
             throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
         }

         var jsonString = bindingContext.ActionContext.HttpContext.Request.Body;
         using var reader = new StreamReader(jsonString);
         var body = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();

         if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(body))
         {
             return;
         }
         var inputJson = JObject.Parse(body);
         var forms = inputJson["forms"];
         var cyber = forms["cyber"];
         foreach (var form in cyber)
         {
             if ((bool)form.First["selected"])
             {
                 foreach (var property in form.First.Children<JProperty>())
                 {
                     if (property.Name != "selected")
                     {
                         property.Value = null;
                     }
                 }
             }
         }

         var outputJson = inputJson.ToString();
         var requestModel = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RequestModel>(outputJson);

         bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(requestModel);
     }
}
```

When I send data:
[image]
API returned data:
[image]